event.preventDefault cannot block clipboard paste in chatgpt.com prompt box
I'm using following code to block paste to certain webpages:
document.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
});

It works in most cases except for prompt box in https://chatgpt.com. Here is what I did step by step:

Open https://chatgpt.com with chrome for Windows.
Open console and run above codes.
Copy some texts and paste to prompt box with CTL+V or right-click -> paste.
Text is pasted successfully.

I wonder how it pastes text and is there any way to block it?
Update:
Thanks to @Unmitigated, ChatGPT works now with useCapture set to true.
document.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
}, true);

However, I find more sites that don't work even with useCapture set to true, for example Gmail:

open https://gmail.com with Chrome on Windows.
Click "Compose" to create a new mail.
Open console and run above codes.
Copy some text and paste to email content.
Text is pasted successfully.


You could use event capturing and also stop the event from propagating.
document.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}, true);


Thanks @Unmitigated, chatgpt.com works now, but i found that this solution doesn't work for gmail compose email dialog. question updated.

@SantK You can also stop the event's propagation.

@SantK Glad to help.
